# How to push and pop until to a specific route in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

I am making an application, In my sign out dialog, i got this code.

```
  Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                  return AuthScreen();
                }), (route) {
                  // if( route is (MaterialPageRoute('/')))
                  // {

                  // }
                  // print(route);
                  return false;
                });
```

I just want to push AuthScreen and remove until the route screen. How to do that?

So after this code, stack contains root screen, and AuthScreen.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this:

```dart
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
    context,   
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => AuthScreen()), 
    ModalRoute.withName('/') // Replace this with your root screen's route name (usually '/')
);
```

Another way you can try is:

```
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => AuthScreen()),
  (Route<dynamic> route) => route is RootPage (your root page's type)
);
```

Yet another one:

```dart
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => AuthScreen()),
  (Route<dynamic> route) => route.isFirst (pop until your first page)
);
```

Sample app:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:in_app_update/in_app_update.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => MyHome(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class MyHome extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHome({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Sample App'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyChild())),
          child: Text('To child page'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyChild extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyChild({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('My Child'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) => MySecondChild()),
              ModalRoute.withName('/')),
          child: Text('Push to Second Child and remove until homepage'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MySecondChild extends StatelessWidget {
  const MySecondChild({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('My Second Child'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
          child: Text('Pop'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried with this but I got black screen

Comment: is there any way without named routes

Comment: In case of black screen, did you set `initialRoute` as '/'  in your `MaterialApp` ? I updated the alternative in my answer above as well.

Comment: yes.    '/': (context) => MyHome(),

Comment: i didnt get it . what is root page's type?

Comment: @maheshmahi it's `MyHome` in your case

Comment: could you please show me. in code.

Comment: @maheshmahi you can check the sample app I included in the answer

Comment: thanks for your valuable time and answer. I am checking now.

Comment: I dont know why, after getting AuthScreen when back button taps, it closes the app.

Comment: thanks bro.. it worked. means route.isFirst

Comment: @Back I think I was using the same class for two classes. one for route and other for other class.

Comment: @maheshmahi Glad my answer can help! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Writing this answer considering other cases people might have and looking for a solution.

If you've implemented your own custom PageRoute/PageRoutBuilder and using this everywhere to push and pop pages, the suggested answer might not work. At least, that was it in my case.

One way to overcome this problem would be, by using named routes like everybody (and the doc itself) suggests. But regardless of the “Why”, if you don't want to go in that way, I came here to propose a new solution.

1. **You can give your** own **PageRoute** implementation **an instance variable**, say a String (but don't. At least use an enum if you really want to pursue this path), where this variable would be your page's name (like `HomePageView`). Later, when you wish to pushAndRemoveUntil until, write the second argument like below:

> ```dart
> Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
>     MyCustomPageBuilder(MyStatelessView()),
>     (Route<dynamic> route) {
>         if (route is MyCustomPageBuilder && route.instanceVariable == 'HomePageView') {
>              return true;
>         }
>         return false;
>     }
> );
> ```

2. You can design your custom PageRoute implementation as Generic, and while pushing new pages you could write:

> `Navigator.of(context).push(MyCustomPageBuilder<HomePageView>)`

and then, while pushing your `MyStatelessView` and popping the previous pages until `HomePageView`, you could write:

> ```dart
> Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
>     MyCustomPageBuilder<MyStatelessView>(MyStatelessView()),
>     (Route<dynamic> route) {
>         if (route is MyCustomPageBuilder<HomePageView>) {
>              return true;
>         }
>         return false;
>     }
> );
> ```

They both will work. But I suggest you to go with second one.